# Ignore SSL certificate in RestFar library

Tags: rest, uwp, ssl-certificate

I am using the Restfar library to consume an API-REST from UWP. Everything works fine when I consume the API on the server because the SSL certificate matches this one, but when I work in local it does not work for me. I want to ignore certificates locally but I can not find an option. Does anyone know how to disable them or ignore the certificates in this library?. Thank you =)

In remote code:

```
var ssl_options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./keys/file.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./keys/file.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./keys/file.ca-bundle')
};

var api = require('./routes/routes');
var app = express();
var secureServer = https.createServer(ssl_options, app);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('...', '...');
    ...
    next();

    });
app.use(forceSSL);
app.use('/apirest', api);

secureServer.listen(portNumber);
```

In local code:

```
//var ssl_options = {
//    key: fs.readFileSync('./keys/file.key'),
//    cert: fs.readFileSync('./keys/file.crt'),
//    ca: fs.readFileSync('./keys/file.ca-bundle')
//};
var api = require('./routes/routes');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('...', '...');
    ...
    next();
});
//app.use(forceSSL);
app.use('/apirest', api);
server.listen(portNumber);
```

Comment: Did you mean [this library](https://github.com/forehalo/Restfar)? And please show the code snippet that you mentioned not work.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, that is the library. When I make the request to a URL that I have on a properly certified remote server, I have no problems. The problem is that I use the same server certificates locally and it is obvious that they tell me that they do not agree, what I do not want is to change from https to https to test locally (I do it now) but to see if there is any way to ignore the certificates, the message of the exception that launches me is: "Http Request return with a exception, please check your network.". I have the API in NodeJS and express with MongoDB.